# Check if user clicks on client besides them

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, multiplayer

I'm trying to detect if a user clicks on a client besides them. If you try the project (https://multiplayer-movement.stcollier.repl.co/) and open the console, (move with arrow keys) if you click on yourself, the console returns `true` but this doesn't work with if you click on any other client. Here's my JavaScript:

```js
var socket = io();
var player; //var player = players[id]
//let fps = performance.now();
let playerWidth = 25;
let playerHeight = 25;

var movement = {
  up: false,
  down: false,
  left: false,
  right: false
}
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  switch (event.keyCode) {
    case 37: //Arrow LEFT
      movement.left = true;
      break;
    case 38: //Arrow UP
      movement.up = true;
      break;
    case 39: //Arrow RIGHT
      movement.right = true;
      break;
    case 40: //Arrow Down
      movement.down = true;
      break;
  }
});
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  switch (event.keyCode) {
    case 37: //Arrow LEFT
      movement.left = false;
      break;
    case 38: //Arrow UP
      movement.up = false;
      break;
    case 39: //Arrow RIGHT
      movement.right = false;
      break;
    case 40: //Arrow Down
      movement.down = false;
      break;
  }
});

socket.emit('new player');

/*var lastUpdateTime = (new Date()).getTime();
setInterval(function() {
  socket.emit('movement', movement);
  var currentTime = (new Date()).getTime();
  timeDifference = currentTime - lastUpdateTime;
  lastUpdateTime = currentTime;
}, 1000 / 60);*/

setInterval(function() {
  socket.emit('movement', movement);
}, 1000 / 60);

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
//ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
socket.on('state', function(players) {
  //console.log(players);
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  for (var id in players) {
    player = players[id];
    ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
    ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, playerWidth, playerHeight)
  }
});

function canShoot(p2, event) {
  var mouseX = event.clientX;
  var mouseY = event.clientY;
  if (mouseX >= p2.x && mouseX <= p2.x + playerWidth && mouseY >= p2.y && mouseY <= mouseY + playerHeight) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
document.body.onclick = function() {
    if (canShoot(player, event)) {
    console.log(true)
  }
}
```

My function that detects if a user clicks on a client is here:

```js
function canShoot(p2, event) {
  var mouseX = event.clientX;
  var mouseY = event.clientY;
  if (mouseX >= p2.x && mouseX <= p2.x + playerWidth && mouseY >= p2.y && mouseY <= mouseY + playerHeight) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

And here is my server code:

```js
const http = require("http");
const express = require("express");
const socketio = require("socket.io");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();
const httpserver = http.Server(app);
const io = socketio(httpserver);

const gamedirectory = path.join(__dirname, "public");

app.use(express.static(gamedirectory));

httpserver.listen(3000);

var players = {};
let speed = 4;
var timeDifference;

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log("A user connected.")
  socket.on('new player', function() { //adds client on connection
    players[socket.id] = {
      x: 0, //x and y spawn point
      y: 0
    };
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('A user disconnected.');
    delete players[socket.id]; //deletes client on disconnection
  });
  socket.on('movement', function(data) {
    var player = players[socket.id] || {};
    if (data.left) {
      player.x -= speed;
    }
    if (data.up) {
      player.y -= speed;
    }
    if (data.right) {
      player.x += speed;
    }
    if (data.down) {
      player.y += speed;
    }
  });
});

/*setInterval(function() {
  io.sockets.emit('state', players);
}, 1000 / 60);*/

var lastUpdateTime = (new Date()).getTime();
setInterval(function() {
  io.sockets.emit('state', players);
  var currentTime = (new Date()).getTime();
  timeDifference = currentTime - lastUpdateTime;
  lastUpdateTime = currentTime;
}, 1000 / 60);
```

So how would I fix this issue, so that if the user clicks, they can click on other clients?

Thanks.

Comment: when you call the canShoot you are using the global variable player, which seems to be the last player property in your players object. As it happens, this is your player. Your canShoot function returns true if you click anywhere on that global player, which is your player, so it will return true.

Comment: You should add the click event to each players sprite. Check that the clicked sprite is not the users sprite.

Comment: @about14sheep could you please elaborate on how to check if the clicked sprite is not the users sprite?

Comment: assign an id when the user instantiates a player object. If the id of player clicked equals the users id, you are clicking on your player

Comment: I would also suggest you look into a game engine if you are not using one. I personally liked [phaser](https://phaser.io/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue you are having is here:

```
for (var id in players) {
    player = players[id];
    ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
    ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, playerWidth, playerHeight)
}
```

The loop will keep going until it reaches the last player. This means that your 'player' variable will be reassigned every time the loop goes around until it reaches the last player, which is your client and that will be the value of 'player'. Therefore, it can only see the coordinates of your player.

Try this instead:

```
var socket = io();
let player = []; // array of ALL players
//let fps = performance.now();
let playerWidth = 25;
let playerHeight = 25;

var movement = {
  up: false,
  down: false,
  left: false,
  right: false
}
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  switch (event.keyCode) {
    case 37: //Arrow LEFT
      movement.left = true;
      break;
    case 38: //Arrow UP
      movement.up = true;
      break;
    case 39: //Arrow RIGHT
      movement.right = true;
      break;
    case 40: //Arrow Down
      movement.down = true;
      break;
  }
});
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  switch (event.keyCode) {
    case 37: //Arrow LEFT
      movement.left = false;
      break;
    case 38: //Arrow UP
      movement.up = false;
      break;
    case 39: //Arrow RIGHT
      movement.right = false;
      break;
    case 40: //Arrow Down
      movement.down = false;
      break;
  }
});

socket.emit('new player');

/*var lastUpdateTime = (new Date()).getTime();
setInterval(function() {
  socket.emit('movement', movement);
  var currentTime = (new Date()).getTime();
  timeDifference = currentTime - lastUpdateTime;
  lastUpdateTime = currentTime;
}, 1000 / 60);*/

setInterval(function() {
  socket.emit('movement', movement);
}, 1000 / 60);

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
//ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
socket.on('state', function(players) {
  //console.log(players);
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  let i = 0;
  for (var id in players) {
    player[player.length] = players[id];
    ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
    ctx.fillRect(player[i].x, player[i].y, playerWidth, playerHeight)
    i++;
  }
});

function canShoot(p2, event) {
  var mouseX = event.clientX;
  var mouseY = event.clientY;
  for (var i = 0; i < p2.length; i++) {
  if (mouseX >= p2[i].x && mouseX <= p2[i].x + playerWidth && mouseY >= p2[i].y && mouseY <= mouseY + playerHeight) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
}
document.body.onclick = function() {
    if (canShoot(player, event)) {
    console.log(true)
  }
}
```

Notice that I changed the variable to be an Array.

```
let player = [];
```

That way, you could detect if any player was clicked on, not just the last one from the loop (your player). Then, I added a loop here:

```
for (var i = 0; i < p2.length; i++) {
  if (mouseX >= p2[i].x && mouseX <= p2[i].x + playerWidth && mouseY >= p2[i].y && mouseY <= mouseY + playerHeight) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
 }
}
```

This will loop through to see if ANY player was clicked.

Finally, I changed this:

```
player = players[id];
```

To this:

```
player[player.length] = players[id];
```

To give each player its own spot in the Array, that way you can have multiple players to check, not just yourself.

Comment: I tried adding your code, but now my player won't even show up. Maybe this is because it's conflicting with my server code?
https://multiplayer-movement.stcollier.repl.co/

Edit: I added the server code to the question.

Comment: This is why it won't draw. Replace your 'for-in' loop with this: `.                          
let i = 0;             
for (var id in players) {
    player[player.length] = players[id];
    ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
    ctx.fillRect(player[i].x, player[i].y, playerWidth, playerHeight); i++;                                           
        }` Sorry about  that!